# Monty Hall program c++

Tags: c++

For my programming class we are making a program that simulates the Monty Hall problem, but switches the door every time after "revealing" the wrong door instead of the user choosing. The percentage when switching is supposed to be around 66%, but my program keeps returning the split 50-50.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int getRandom(int low, int high, int badNum) {
    int random = rand() % high + low;

    while (random == badNum) {
        random = rand() % high + low;
    }

    return random;
}

int main() {

    int guess = 0;
    int winningNum = 0;
    int elimNum = 0;
    int switchedNum = 0;
    int switchCount = 0;

    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));

    cout << "Please enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    cin.get();

    while (guess < 1 || guess > 3) {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
        cin >> guess;
        cin.get();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {

        winningNum = getRandom(1, 3, 0);
        elimNum = getRandom(1, 3, winningNum);
        switchedNum = getRandom(1, 3, elimNum);

        while (switchedNum == guess) {
            switchedNum = getRandom(1, 3, elimNum);
        }

        if (switchedNum == winningNum) { switchCount++; }
    }

    cout << "You won " << switchCount / 10 << "% of the time, and lost  " << 100 - (switchCount / 10) << "% of the time.";


    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In C++ it's [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to call [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)  recursively in *any* way. Use loops instead!

Comment: Shouldn't `switchedNum` represent the door that is neither the one that was first chosen (`guess`) nor the door that was revealed (`elimNum`)? I don't see why it's random.

Comment: Now for the next request: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If rubber-duck debugging or print-debugging (which is only mentioned in a comment) doesn't help, then step through the code line by line in a debugger. If doing that, you can at the same time monitor variables and their values, as well partially evaluate simple expressions to see their results.

Comment: I also recommend you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) about "finding a simpler problem". Simplify your code as much as you can, try to narrow down the problem to a small specific piece of code.

Comment: Lastly, [random number generators](https://imgur.com/gallery/uR4WuQ0) can be quite nasty to get expected result. For debugging, use a fixed specific seed that generates a well-known sequence of numbers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It seems even though `switchedNum` is picked at random the final value won't be random at all because it would always be the remaining third number not equal to `guess` and `elimNum`. I think the problem is that `elimNum = getRandom(1, 3, winningNum);` while it should also be not equal to guessed number.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that `elimNum = getRandom(1, 3, winningNum);`, that is only checked not to be equal to the `winningNum` while it should also be not equal to `guessed` number. This will make result be expected 66%:

```
elimNum = getRandom(1, 3, winningNum);
while (elimNum == guess) {
     elimNum = getRandom(1, 3, winningNum);
}
```